# How can I write this shorter?

Tags: c#

```
public static string GetUa(HttpRequest hr)
{
    try
    {
        string visitorBrowser = hr.UserAgent.ToString();
        string originalBrowser = hr.ServerVariables["X-OperaMini-Phone-UA"];
        string anotherOriginalBrowser = hr.ServerVariables["X-Device-User-Agent"]; //novarra

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(originalBrowser))
        {
            return "OPERAMINI " + originalBrowser;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(anotherOriginalBrowser))
            {
                return "NOVARRA " + anotherOriginalBrowser;
            }
            else
            {
                return visitorBrowser;
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return "No UA Found";
    }
}
```

Comment: Calling `ToString()` on `hr.UserAgent` is not necessary because it's already a string and will eliminate using exceptions as part of your method flow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd be more concerned with readability. This seems nicer to me:

```
var operaAgent = hr.ServerVariables["X-OperaMini-Phone-UA"];
var deviceAgent = hr.ServerVariables["X-Device-User-Agent"];

operaAgent = string.IsNullOrEmpty(operaAgent) ? null : "OPERAMINI" + operaAgent;
deviceAgent = string.IsNullOrEmpty(deviceAgent) ? null : "NOVARRA" + deviceAgent;

return operaAgent ?? deviceAgent ?? hr.UserAgent ?? "Not Found";
```

Of course, if you didn't need to prefix those strings onto the UAs and didn't need to concern yourself with empty string user agents, then it would simply be:

```
return hr.ServerVariables["X-OperaMini-Phone-UA"] ??
       hr.ServerVariables["X-Device-User-Agent"] ??
       hr.UserAgent ??
       "Not Found";
```

Comment: I completely forgot about the coalesce operator. Good call. Except one detail: You're not handling the `Empty` portion of `IsNullOrEmpty`. A minor detail, admittedly, one you can correct with a quick edit. (I still +1ed you; right idea.)

Comment: +1 for readability as well as conciseness; although I'd turn the second `if` statement into an `else if` (shorter, and faster too if the first check succeeds).

Comment: However the code is wrong. != null is not the same as in the original code.

Comment: Wow, picky picky :)  I don't have enough context to know whether an empty string is expected. That would only happen if someone is populating that value with an empty string, and I assumed that that wouldn't happen in order to simplify the code. The OP has the context to know whether that is OK.

Comment: Sorry to be picky, but the question was "How can I write *this* shorter?", not how can I write some code that has nice readability but has nothing to do with the original code.

Comment: There are many bots, half baked mobile browsers that sends empty or no UA

Comment: No problem. I've modified the code to check for "" too. Not as succinct, but still bearable.

Comment: Sorry, but now it's COMPLETELY wrong. Actually it shows why using var is not really a good idea sometimes.

Comment: You could eliminate the two if statements if you append on "OPERAMINI" and "NOVARRA" in the ternaries. By then you already know that they aren't null.

Comment: I don't necessarily need OPERA and NOVARRA

return hr.ServerVariables["X-OperaMini-Phone-UA"] ??
       hr.ServerVariables["X-Device-User-Agent"] ??
       hr.UserAgent ??
       "Not Found";

looks good to me

Comment: OK, well I've fixed it up anyway. Not sure how var has anything to do with it - more a case of posting untested, uncompiled code (I'm running linux at the moment, no mono).

Comment: @nLL If you're going with the second example and you want a null UA treated the same as an empty UA, replace "Not Found" with ""

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any way to significantly shorten that.

One way to save a few lines is to get rid of the braces around the first else:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(originalBrowser))
{
    return "OPERAMINI " + originalBrowser;
}
else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(anotherOriginalBrowser))
{
    return "NOVARRA " + anotherOriginalBrowser;
}
else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(visitorBrowser))
{
    return visitorBrowser;
}
else
{
    return "No User Agent Detected";
}
```

You should be careful about using exceptions for flow control, too. statenjason has the right idea.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, what you have is clear and legible. If you're trying to get there with less processing time, I don't think you're going to make it. If you're trying to get there with fewer lines of code, you can, but it's going to be ugly.

One easy way to shorten it on-screen (same LOC count, -1) is to remove some of your curly braces and not store `visitorBrowser`:

```
public static string GetUa(HttpRequest hr)
{
    try
    {
        string originalBrowser = hr.ServerVariables["X-OperaMini-Phone-UA"];
        string anotherOriginalBrowser = hr.ServerVariables["X-Device-User-Agent"]; //novarra

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(originalBrowser))
            return "OPERAMINI " + originalBrowser;
        else
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(anotherOriginalBrowser))
                return "NOVARRA " + anotherOriginalBrowser;
            else
                return hr.UserAgent.ToString();
    }
    catch
    {
        return "No UA Found";
    }
}
```

To me, this is slightly less readable, but probably still livable.

Now you can make it **really** short by using the conditional operator (`?:`), but it's going to also be **really** nasty for readability. If I saw code like the following in a code review, I'd make the developer rewrite it for clarity:

```
public static string GetUa(HttpRequest hr)
{
    try
    {
        string visitorBrowser = hr.UserAgent.ToString();
        string originalBrowser = hr.ServerVariables["X-OperaMini-Phone-UA"];
        string anotherOriginalBrowser = hr.ServerVariables["X-Device-User-Agent"]; //novarra

        return !(string.IsNullOrEmpty(originalBrowser)) ? "OPERAMINI " + originalBrowser :
               !(string.IsNullOrEmpty(anotherOriginalBrowser)) ? "NOVARRA " + anotherOriginalBrowser : visitorBrowser);
    }
    catch 
    {
        return "No UA Found";
    }
}
```

Seriously, **please** don't do the second example. (I'm not 100% sure that will compile; I'm writing it off the top of my head on my Mac at the moment. But I'm 99.9% sure it will, and will work, and the next developer will HATE you for it.)

Comment: Am I the only person who finds that second piece extremely readable then? :)

Comment: I love the conditional operator, but I *hate* chaining them together. With two conditions, it's not too bad, but with 3 or more, I find the readability seriously lacking.

Comment: Fair enough. For me, if I can line them up the way you have here, it's still readable, no matter how many there are. I can see there's a '?' on each line, so I know what you're doing. I might be temped to drop 'visitorBrowser' to it's own line to say "this is the catch-all, at the end here". Where I do hate chained ternaries is where the chain is not always at the end. eg. 'A=1 ? B : C=1 ? D : E=1 ? F : G' is readable to me 'A=1 ? B=1 ? C : D : E=1 ? F : G' is not, even if you parenthesise it.

Answer (score 1):

Like this, for example:

```
public static string GetUa(HttpRequest hr) {
  try {
    string originalBrowser = hr.ServerVariables["X-OperaMini-Phone-UA"];
    string anotherOriginalBrowser = hr.ServerVariables["X-Device-User-Agent"];
    return
      !String.IsNullOrEmpty(originalBrowser) ? "OPERAMINI " + originalBrowser :
      !String.IsNullOrEmpty(anotherOriginalBrowser) ? "NOVARRA " + anotherOriginalBrowser :
      hr.UserAgent;
  } catch {
    return "No UA Found";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this (everything else is just extra code doing nothing):

```
public static string GetUa(HttpRequest hr) 
{ 
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(hr.ServerVariables["X-OperaMini-Phone-UA"])) 
        return "OPERAMINI " + hr.ServerVariables["X-OperaMini-Phone-UA"])) ; 
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(hr.ServerVariables["X-Device-User-Agent"])) 
        return "NOVARRA " +   hr.ServerVariables["X-Device-User-Agent"])) ; 
    return hr.UserAgent ?? "Not Found"; 
}
```

**And you should NEVER use exceptions in your normal application flow path.**

Comment: But were do you get `originalBrowser` and `anotherOriginalBrowser` from?

Comment: Overlooked that, fixed it *g*

Comment: Out of curiosity which one is faster? Assigning to string or requesting same servervariable couple of times?

Comment: It doesn't really matter. It's not "requesting" it from a server *g*. It just retrieves it from an index and the complexity is still O(1) which is the same as a simple string assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a condensed version. Because you're `return`ing inside each `if` statement, you can eliminate your `else`s. Also, I eliminated the need for using exceptions for flow.

```
    public static string GetUa(HttpRequest hr)
    {
        string visitorBrowser = hr.UserAgent;
        string originalBrowser = hr.ServerVariables["X-OperaMini-Phone-UA"];
        string anotherOriginalBrowser = hr.ServerVariables["X-Device-User-Agent"]; //novarra
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(visitorBrowser))
            return "No UA Found";
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(originalBrowser))
            return "OPERAMINI " + originalBrowser;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(anotherOriginalBrowser))
            return "NOVARRA " + anotherOriginalBrowser;
        return visitorBrowser;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string GetUa(HttpRequest hr)
{
    try
    {
        string visitorBrowser = hr.UserAgent.ToString();
        string originalBrowser = hr.ServerVariables["X-OperaMini-Phone-UA"];
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(originalBrowser)) return "OPERAMINI"+originalBrowser;
        string anotherOriginalBrowser = hr.ServerVariables["X-Device-User-Agent"]; //novarra
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(anotherOriginalBrowser)) return "NOVARRA" + anotherOriginalBrowser;
        return visitorBrowser;
    }
    catch
    {
        return "No UA Found";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

second if-statment:

```
return (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(anotherOriginalBrowser) ? ("NOVARRA " + anotherOriginalBrowser) : visitorBrowser);
```

You can probably use this combined with the first if-statment too

Answer (score 0):

I don't like when it is doing work that it doesn't have to do.  So I would write it as follows:

```
   public static string GetUa(HttpRequest hr)
    {
        string browser = hr.ServerVariables["X-OperaMini-Phone-UA"];
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(browser))
            return "OPERAMINI " + browser;

        browser = hr.ServerVariables["X-Device-User-Agent"]; //novarra 
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(browser))
            return "NOVARRA " + browser;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(hr.UserAgent))
            return hr.UserAgent;

        return "No UA Found";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more dynamic .NET 4 approach:

```
    private static readonly Tuple<string, string>[] SpecialUas =
        {
            Tuple.Create("X-OperaMini-Phone-UA", "NOVARRA"),
            Tuple.Create("X-Device-User-Agent", "OPERAMINI")
        };

    public static string GetUa(HttpRequest r)
    {
        return (
                   from specialUa in SpecialUas
                   let serverVariable = r.ServerVariables[specialUa.Item1]
                   where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(serverVariable)
                   select string.Concat(specialUa.Item2, " ", serverVariable)
               ).FirstOrDefault() ?? (
                   string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.UserAgent)
                   ? "No UA Found"
                   : r.UserAgent
               );
    }
```

This can be customised with additional special UAs very easily by adding further tuples.

It wouldn't be difficult to replace the tuples with something else if you're not running on .NET 4.